# Kill Infinite loop at Upstart's run level

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kill, runlevel, upstart

One of my applications is at a infinite loop in the runlevel 1 by printing *No protocol specified* continuously after running `startx -- :1`.
The run level does not listen to my commands given at the run level.
I can of course give kernel Magic*B, but that would close all my other run levels which I do not want. Magic*K is not working.

One nasty way of stopping the run level is by removing components such as `/etc/rc1.d/*.*bluetooth.*`. However, I do not see this a good way in the long run.

**How can you kill all processes at the run level 1 which belongs to the open prompt in the given run level?**

Comment: I think you'll have better luck at superuser.com.

Comment: your use of the term "runlevel" is confusing.  the system is only in a single runlevel at a time.  could you please clarify?  maybe give the steps you're using to arrive at the problem state.  like this: "1. boot into runlevel 1; 2. run `startx -- :1` ; 3. can't `kill -9` it and nothing works!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way to do this would be to use [`update-rc.d`](http://www.annodex.net/cgi-bin/man/man2html?update-rc.d+8). You can configure the program to not run at all during runlevel 1:

```
$update-rc.d script_name stop 1 .
```

where `script_name` is the init.d script. So for example, to stop Apache from running in runlevel 1:

```
$update-rc.d apache2 stop 1 .
```

If you want to **completely disable** the specified service:

```
$update-rc.d -f script_name remove
```

If you are going to disable a service, you should also stop it from running in all runlevels. Next time a service is upgraded, the init.d scripts may be recreated, essentially re-enabling your service.

To disable it in **all runlevels**:

```
$update-rc.d script_name stop 80 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 .
```

Comment: I get the following warnings http://paste.pocoo.org/show/158523/

Comment: Oh, apache was just an example! what program is giving you the errors? Is it bluetooth or another application?